# awk and bash script?

Tags: bash, awk, command, sh

I wonder why it doesn't work.
Please advise me.

***1. working***

```
$ nu=`awk '/^Mem/ {printf($2*0.7);}' <(free -m)`
$ echo $nu
1291.5
```

***2. not working***

```
$ cat test.sh
#!/bin/bash
nu=`awk '/^Mem/ {printf($2*0.7);}' <(free -m)`
echo $nu
$ sh test.sh  
test.sh: command substitution: line 2: syntax error near unexpected token `('
test.sh: command substitution: line 2: `awk '/^Mem/ {printf($2*0.7);}' <(free -m)'
```

Comment: Use `bash test.sh`.

Comment: Your `/bin/sh` implementation is `dash` or another one that doesn't support `<(command)` redirection.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Could you please try following.

```
nu=$(free -m | awk '/^Mem/ {print $2*0.7}')
echo "$nu"
```

Things taken care are:

- Use of backtick is depreciated so use `$` to store variable's value.
- Also first run `free` command pass its standard output as standard input to `awk` command by using `|`(which should be ideal way of sending output of a command to `awk` in this scenario specially) and save its output to a variable named `nu`.
- Now finally print variable `nu` by `echo`.
- Since `<(...)` process substitution is supported by bash not by sh so I am trying to give a solution where it could support without process substitution (which I mentioned a bit earlier too).

Answer (score 2):

The `<( )` construct ("process substitution") is not available in all shells, or even in bash when it's invoked with the name "sh". When you run the script with `sh test.sh`, that overrides the shebang (which specifies bash), so that feature is not available. You need to either run the script explicitly with `bash`, or (better) just run it as `./test.sh` and let the shebang line do its job.

Answer (score 1):

The reason to add a [shebang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)) in a script is to define an interpreter directive if the file has execution permission.

Then, you should invoke it by, for example

```
$ ./test.sh
```

once you have set the permission

```
$ chmod +x test.sh
```